# Grouping items with group by having

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have the following database:

```
id product color group
1 chair blue 1
2 chair yellow 1
3 chair brown 1
4 table pink 2
5 table red 2
6 carpet cyan -1
7 sofa white 3
8 sofa green 3
9 curtains black -1
```

I want to get a product id from each group plus all the products that don't belong to any group, ie, group=-1:

```
id product
1 chair
4 table
6 carpet
7 sofa
9 curtains
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `products` GROUP BY `group` HAVING `group` != '-1'
```

but it doesn't return the non-group products...

Help, anyone?

Thank you,
Pedro

Comment: It appears from your sample date that group is largely irrelevant? OR can a product belong to more than 1 group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union approach here:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, product
FROM products
WHERE `group` <> -1
GROUP BY product
UNION ALL
SELECT id, product
FROM products
WHERE `group` = -1;
```

The top half of the union query reports one product per group, having the smallest `id`.  The second half reports all products having `group = -1`, without any aggregation.